# Fatal error while appending data with NSMutableData in Swift

Tags: swift

```
Code:     
var webData: NSMutableData!

 func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
  println(data.length)
  webData .appendData(data)
 }
```

I am getting the following **error**:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

What is wrong with my code?. Any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: You should provide more information e.g. how did you call NSURLConnection and full stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialise your variable. Try this:

```
var webData = NSMutableData()  // was: var webData: NSMutableData!
```